# Java generics to assign global variables

Tags: java, generics, global-variables, comparable

In this example, I get the warning that "List is a raw type." How can I use generics to properly satisfy this warning? I'm having trouble because I can't figure out how to define "T" for the global variable like I was able to for the constructor signature.

```
public class MyClass{

    private List input;

    public <T extends Comparable<T>> MyClass(List<T> input){
        this.input = input;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should probably make the entire class generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must define your class as parameterized

```
public class MyClass<T extends Comparable<T>>{

    private List<T> input;

    public MyClass(List<T> input){
        this.input = input;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

'Raw Types' refer to generic types that have not had their generic parameter types specific. In this case, this is because you've omitted the generic type in your declaration of `input`. Changing the declaration to:

```
private List<T> input;
```

Should resolve the error. In addition, your constructor declaration doesn't need generic parameters, and can be shortened to:

```
public MyClass(List<T> input){
    this.input = input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to do something like:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    private List<T> input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've seen, the issue is caused by your member variable `input` using `List` without a generic parameter. Hence, the type is being used "raw". To resolve this, you have three options. You can:

1. Make your whole class generic

   ```
   public class MyClass<T extends Comparable<T>> {

       private List<T> input;

       public MyClass(List<T> input) {
           this.input = input;
       }

   }
   ```

or

2. Use a wildcard

   ```
   private List<? extends Comparable<T>> input;
   ```

or

3. Rethink your strategy

   ```
    public class MyClass {

        private List<Comparable<T>> input;

        public <T extends Comparable<T>> MyClass(List<T> input) {
            this.input = new LinkedList<>();
            // Obv. there are better ways of copying a list...
            for (Comparable<T> obj : input) {
                this.input.add(obj);
            }
        }

   }
   ```

I would recommend option 1 or 3.

Comment: Option 3 does not work, I get "cannot resolve symbol  'T'" on the class var List<Comparable<T>> input;

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is where you say `private List input;`, you game no parameter for the generic type that it's looking for. You can fix it by saying `private List<T> input;`

Answer (score 0):

You could make the class generic.

```
public class MyClass<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private final List<T> input;

    public MyClass(Collection<? extends T> input){
        this.input = new ArrayList<T>(input);
    }
}
```

I have also changed the line `this.input = input` to instead make a copy of `input`. This is really quite important because otherwise anyone with a reference to `input` could modify your class by modifying `input`. I've also made your constructor a bit more flexible by allowing any `Collection` of any subtype of `T`.